# How can i change the config spec in view properties

Tags: clearcase, vcs-checkout

I want to checkout some developer branch. How can i change the config spec in view properties? It shows default as **element* main/LATEST.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a selection rule *before* the `main/LATEST` one:

```
element * .../devBranch/LATEST
element * main/LATEST
```

You can do that with:

```
cd /path/to/myview
cleartool edcs
```

The best practice is to create a separate view for that, preferably a dynamic view (that way you can fiddle with the config spec and see quickly if the selected content matches your need).
Once the config spec is valid, you can apply it to a new snapshot view.

Answer (score 0):

One way of changing config specs is mentioned below:-

```
$ ct edcs 
//Mention all your config specs here
//Save and exit(:wq)
```

Note: edcs(edit config specs)